# How to append space before match pattern in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How to append number of space before match pattern or after line by line in bash with sed command?

**file.txt**

```
str_len: equ $ - str    ; calcs length of string (bytes) by
          ; subtracting this address ($ symbol)
```

**output.txt**

```
str_len: equ $ - str    ; calcs length of string (bytes) by
                        ; subtracting this address ($ symbol)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just a tool from unix-magic-set-of-wondrous-things that does exactly what you want:

```
$ column -t -s ';' -o ';' <input>
str_len: equ $ - str    ; calcs length of string (bytes) by
                        ; subtracting this address ($ symbol)
```

Other than that, sed is Turing complete, and so is Turing's machine. But that does not mean one has time to implement *non-trivial* solutions on such *architectures* :D

*Edit*: The above command was run using `column from util-linux 2.25.2`, with flags:

> ```
> -o, --output-separator string
>    Specify the columns delimiter for table output (default is two spaces).
>
> -s, --separator separators
>    Specify the possible input item delimiters (default is whitespace).
>
> -t, --table
>    Determine  the  number  of  columns  the input contains and create a table.
>    Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with  the  characters
>    supplied  using  the --output-separator option.  Table output is useful for
>    pretty-printing.
> ```

Comment: Though I don't see the `-o` in some manuals +1 for chose the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
$ awk -F' *;' -vOFS=\; '{print $1 substr("                        ",1,24-length($1)),$2}' file.txt
str_len: equ $ - str    ; calcs length of string (bytes) by
                        ; subtracting this address ($ symbol)
```

Set the input field separator to any number of spaces followed by a semicolon. Set the output field separator to a semicolon. Print the first column, followed by as many spaces as are needed to pad to 24 characters, followed by the second column.